# How to visualize Kafka topic messages in Grafana?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana

Edited:

I've successfully configured the Kafka data source into Grafana, but how do I display the messages of my 'temp-sensor' topic in a dashboard? Those are temperature value output from the ds18x20 sensor as shown in the figure below from the Kafka console consumer.

[Kafka console consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNhRC.png)

The topic is able to consume all the temperature values when the sensor is running, however, when I try to visualize the temperature data in Grafana, the time-series chart is not showing any value accordingly when I've already done the Kafka configuration.

[Kafka dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzeeb.png)

This is what I did -

[Kafka data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbgfn.png)
/ [Kafka topics describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afLgd.png)

Kafka-python lib in python3 -

```
import socket
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'), bootstrap_servers='kafka.develop.com.my:9092')
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 1024))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt, adr=s.accept()
    print(f"Connection to {adr} established")
    while True:
        data = clt.recv(1024)
        f = float(data)
        print('Received', data)
        temp = {"temp":f}
        producer.send('temp-sensor', value=temp)
    clt.close()
```

Also, I've added Prometheus data source and imported [Kafka Overview dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/721-kafka/) into Grafana. The dashboard shows that there are messages/bytes received from the 'temp-sensor' topic when I run to code.

[Kafka Overview - Prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6tY.png)

So, I'm wondering what I have missed out or done wrong that my Kafka data source isn't displaying messages in the chart.

Comment: Please show code as text, not images

Comment: You've set auto offset reset as latest. That'll skip any existing data, so try producing new data. Also, aren't you missing timestamps in the data? Otherwise, how does Grafana render data from "the last hour"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the message timestamp in Kafka Producer defaults to current time, and in Grafana I've set the timestamp mode to current so is it necessary to add the timestamps parameter when sending the messages?

Comment: Depends on the Python library used, or if it's been fixed, but I recall a few years ago kafka-python I think defaulted to a record timestamp of -1 if not explicitly set. It wouldn't hurt to add `time.now()`. Try encoding with utf8, too, not ASCII

Comment: It's still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what DataSource you are using, but this one under [Known Limitations](https://github.com/hoptical/grafana-kafka-datasource#known-limitations) says it only accepts JSON, not single floating point values, so update your Python code to use `value=json.dumps({"value1": data})`

They even have their own [Python producer example](https://github.com/hoptical/grafana-kafka-datasource/blob/main/example/python/sample_producer.py).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Kafka DataSource that you mentioned here. I noticed the example given and I followed exactly as it showed, the only change is the bootstrap server configuration, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I've edited my code above but I'm using Kafka Python lib instead of Confluent Kafka lib that is shown in the example. The JSON format of the messages produced/received seems to be correct.

Comment: The library used isn't relevant. Did you try running the example code they provided? If that doesn't work, then file an issue in the repo.

Comment: Yea I did but it doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't used the plugin. You will need to get help from the person that developed it. But also, it doesn't seem to be really maintained. Try using an official Datasource from Grafana like Postgres, Influx or Elastic and write your Kafka data to those systems using tools like Kafka Connect.

Comment: @latteishorse_ Looking at your code again, you may want to add `producer.flush()` after sending a few records.